# How to make assigning an american formatted date string into a Date variable work in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

My users input american formatted dates (mm/dd/yyyy). When the model is saved the date attributes turn to nil:

```
my_model.start_date = "07/30/2011"

puts my_model.start_date
nil
```

I get an invalid date error if I do this in the console:

```
Date.parse("07/30/2011")
```

How do you force the app to accept american date format? I know the app should handle localization correctly but a patch is what I need for the short term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a gem that does the same thing and all you have to do is put this in your gem file:

```
gem 'american_date'
```

I know this is a sort of old post, but i figured this may help other people and is a little easier than the monkey patch.

Answer (score 2):

After much digging around I found this (posted by Troyk in git https://gist.github.com/922048)

```
# Date.parse() with Ruby 1.9 is now defaulting to the European date style where the format is DD/MM/YYYY, not MM/DD/YYYY
# patch it to use US format by default
class Date
  class << self
    alias :euro_parse :_parse
    def _parse(str,comp=false)
      str = str.to_s.strip
      if str == ''
        nil
      elsif str =~ /^(\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{1,2})[-\/](\d{2,4})/
        year,month,day = $3.to_i,$1,$2
        date,*rest = str.split(' ')
        year += (year < 35 ? 2000 : 1900) if year < 100
        euro_parse("#{year}-#{month}-#{day} #{rest.join(' ')}",comp)
      else
        euro_parse(str,comp)
      end  
    end
  end
end
```

Stick this in config/initializiers/american_date_monkey_patch.rb and you are all set.

If your users are not all American then this solution is not for you.